# Representing interaction plot for coxph model using plot_model() in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, cox-model, ggplot2, hazard

I used coxph() to model the latency to a behavior as a function of the levels of a hormone in interaction with the treatment administered. Code for model is as follows

```
M1 <- coxph(Surv(Latency2Behavior, YesOrNo) ~ Hormone*Treatment,
            data = Interaction, ties = "efron")
```

The interaction is significant and can be interpreted as the behavior being more likely to occur in treatment A as the hormone levels increase and less likely to occur in treatment B as the hormone levels increase.

I would like to plot these results graphically and tried to do it using the function plot_model() as follows:

```
plot_model(M1, type = "int", show.data = T)
```

The graph seems to make sense, although I'm not 100% sure of how I should label the y-axis - are those the hazard ratios? I just want to make sure it is ok to use plot_model with the a coxph() type model, whether any transformation is needed, or whether I should use another approach to represent this result.

Thank you in advance for any advice on this, as I am completely new to Cox models.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is seating at the edge of their seats, I think I figured it out:

using type = "emm" in model_plot estimates Risk Factors and is a good enough answer for my problem. You need to add the terms you are interested in.

```
plot_model(M1, type = "emm", terms = c("Hormone", "Treatment"), show.data = T)
```

I hope this is helpful to someone else.